# HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.Long]

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpclient, resttemplate

SpringBoot

RestTemplate Converter add FormHttpMessageConverter.java  and StringHttpMessageConverter and ResourceHttpMessageConverter and ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter,

Http client  Long in params: parts.add("time", time);

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.Long]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writePart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:422)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeParts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:393)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:373)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:733)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:414)
```

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
headers.setAcceptCharset(Collections.singletonList(CharsetUtil.CHARSET_UTF_8));
FileSystemResource zipFile = new FileSystemResource(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
parts.add("time", time);
parts.add("md5", SecureUtil.md5(time + "234234").toUpperCase());
parts.add("file", zipFile);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parts, headers);
```

What HttpMessageConverter   can supports Long ?

Comment: How about adding `time` as a `String` value to the map?  
`parts.add("time", Long.toString(time));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the following message converters are enabled in spring:

```
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter – converts byte arrays
StringHttpMessageConverter – converts Strings
ResourceHttpMessageConverter – converts org.springframework.core.io.Resource for any type of octet stream
SourceHttpMessageConverter – converts javax.xml.transform.Source
FormHttpMessageConverter – converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap<String, String>.
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter – converts Java objects to/from XML (added only if JAXB2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson 2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson is present on the classpath)
AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter – converts Atom feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
RssChannelHttpMessageConverter – converts RSS feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
```

When receiving a new request, Spring will use the “Accept” header to determine the media type that it needs to respond with.In your case , the `FormHttpMessageConverter` is the converter selected by default in spring as you have specified the content type.When writing multipart data, this converter uses other `HttpMessageConverters` to write the respective MIME parts.`FormHttpMessageConverter` class could not find a message converter for the type Long. So you could try converting the Long into string and assigning it to the part like :

```
                Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                parts.add("time", String.valueOf(time));
                parts.add("md5", SecureUtil.md5(time + "234234").toUpperCase());
                parts.add("file", zipFile);
                HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parts, headers);
```

[Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html)

Comment: yes, thanks, see source not supports Long!  but why not supports Long?